# The type or namespace name 'MontlyCalendarView' could not be found

Tags: visual-web-part, visual-studio-2013, solution

I am following this document [Walkthrough: Creating a Web Part for SharePoint by Using a Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231546.aspx)

but I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'MontlyCalendarView' could not be found.
>   Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace SearchCalendars.VisualWebPart1
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public VisualWebPart1()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MonthlyCalendarView mcv = new MonthlyCalendarView();

        }
    }
}
```

I am using SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2013. What's wrong?

Comment: check this article, may be help to fix the problem..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx or this one http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304656

Comment: Checked it but not help. Could it be because I am using SharepPoint 2013? In the requirements of the walkthough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx talks about SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem: when you create your Visual Studio project, select "**Deploy as a farm solution**" instead of "**Deploy as a sandboxed solution**".